# Car goes off flying when game starts

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, rigid-bodies

I have a racing game that I am working on off of a tutorial and at this point, it should be functional, however, when I start the game the car goes flying off and spams an error message which reads "
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "cm" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Rigidbody to the game object "cm". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (UnityEngine.Vector3 force, UnityEngine.ForceMode mode) (at :0)
UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (UnityEngine.Vector3 force) (at :0)
CarController.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/CarController.cs:25)"
I have attached a screenshot of the script in question here -> [screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYBG3.png)

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in the error message?

Comment: reduce spring force on you're wheel collider it will work

Comment: Or set 1400 mass on you're rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

There several reason for this
You have assign the component which don't have rigid-body to code as i think. you have to initialize the component which has the rigid-body component to code (theRB variable)

Rigidbody component must cover every collider most of the time as parent component

- the rigid-body mass value must be above 1000 (most commom  one)
- First may be you have to added any colliders to the mesh   (your 3d object which holds the mesh components)
  add box collider or mesh collider with convex checked
- wheel colliders are not aligned properly - very less common